# Can I set Facebook albums cover photo?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set a photo as Facebook Album's cover.

But I could not find any parameter in graph api documentation.

How can I do ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. From the API documentation:

> You can't update albums using the Graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/album#update